# Lost reputation "User was removed"

Tags: support, reputation

I have lost 10 rep and I don't know why. The message is "User was removed". What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the user account, which upvoted your answer, was deleted.

Please see the Meta Stackoverflow FAQ-tag-FAQ question: [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find something on the first search.

Answer (score 2):

You lost the rep because a user account that had upvoted one of your answers was deleted.