# Reputation -10: User was removed

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I got a -10 reputation on 27th April 2014 with the explanation "User was removed". Hey, I am still able to logon, see all of my previous contributions, so I was not removed. Also, I haven't removed anybody.

As I read in the post [Lost reputation "User was removed"](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3874/lost-reputation-user-was-removed) it means that someone who previously upvoted some of my questions/answers deleted themselves.

Could someone please update the phrasing of the reputation change so we do not need to look-up meta to find out what exactly happened?

Answer (score 9):

This is not because you were removed, but a user who upvoted you (granting you 10 rep) was removed, and with that all the rep the user has spread will be removed as well.

Comment: Correct. It'd be nice if the message was phrased "User who upvoted you was removed"

Comment: That would be a nice wording, indeed. Unfortunately 1) I cannot accept this comment as an answer. 2) The answer for this "question" would be if someone changed the website :)

Answer (score 5):

I think it's fine as worded because the definition you were first inclined to apply is a non sequitur and quickly eliminated.

If your user wasn't removed, and that would make no sense as a reason for reputation to be subtracted from an account that hasn't removed, then it's a very simple jump to it being someone else's user.

Comment: I agree with Andrew on formal logic. Unfortunately even developers are sometimes irrationally behaving humans. Aaaand I have even seen an application that had actual bugs. So I did not have your conclusion without further investigation of what actually could happen.